# combining if conditions inside a lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following code:

```
if (ListOfMyModel.Any(a => a.SomeID != 0 && 
       IsAuthorizedOnID(TheUserID, a.SomeID) == false) == false)
{
    return true;
}
```

Basically, I have a list of objects and I replaced a `foreach` loop with `.Any()` to which I'm passing in a lambda expression.

This code should only return true only if a) all the objects that have SomeID not equal to 0 are authorized in the second function but don't worry about the authorization for the objects that have SomeID equal to 0.

Is my expression correct or are there cases where this may fail?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `!` instead of `== false`

Comment: Also, `!Any(x => x)` can be replaced by `All(x => !x)` (if that makes it easier to deal with).

Comment: SLak's recommendation is universal, not specific to this code.  Don't use `== false` at all.  Don't use `== true` either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding all of that negation, you should write in code exactly what you wrote in your description:

> If every user has ID zero or is authorized.

```
return list.All(a => a.SomeId == 0 || IsAuthorizedOnID(TheUserID, a.SomeID));
```

Comment: @user2864740 The point is that to come up with this Slacks didn't apply demorgan's to the OP's code, he simply rewrote the code based on the spec given, so that the code reads like the spec.

Comment: @SLaks: BTW, is IsAuthorizedOnID(TheUserID, a.SomeID)); the same as IsAuthorizedOnID(TheUserID, a.SomeID) == true); Is the == true condition implicit?

Comment: @frenchie: If `IsAuthorizedOnID()` returns `bool`, it's already either `true` or `false`.  `true == true` is still true, and `false == true` is still false.  Now do you understand? Note that if it returns `bool?`, it's a different story.

Comment: Ok, it returns a bool; I know in Javascript you can leave it implicitly out; didn't know about C#.

Comment: @frenchie: It's not about the language; it's about what boolean means.  `==` is just an operator that returns a bool.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if (!ListOfMyModel.Any(a => a.SomeID != 0 && !IsAuthorizedOnID(TheUserID, a.SomeID))
```

or

```
return ListOfMyModel.All(a => a.SomeId == 0 || IsAuthorizedOnID(TheUserID, a.SomeID));
```